# What is the meaning of Vishwaroopa Sevai in Vishnu Temples?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, puranas, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

What is the meaning of Vishwaroopa Sevai in Vishnu Temples?

Can someone tell me what is the meaning of this sevai?